# How to match first letter of a word and with accent letters in mysql query

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to get the records in which "text" column contains a string strats from that letter or any word in that string starts from that letter.And it should work independent of accents.
For example:

There are 4 records:

```
cafe
astocafe
bad café
good cafes
```

When the user types `cafe`
it should display :

```
cafe
bad café
good cafes
```

I am trying to use this query:

```
SELECT id, texto FROM table WHERE CONVERT( `text` USING utf8 ) REGEXP '[[:<:]]cafe'
```

But its showing only:

```
cafe 
good cafes
```

its not matching accents.

Comment: There are 5 records?

Comment: Its dynamic i have given just an example.it may 4,or 5 or more

Comment: bacause 'é' is special character and you did not consider in your regex.

Comment: Try this regexp: '[[:<:]]caf[eé]'

Comment: @Yash: `é` isn't a specail character, it's an accentuated letter. Like `èàêüù...`.

Comment: @ZuoLi thre may be accents like eéèêëEÉÈÊË or aáàâäAÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ] etc...i have to write every thing in query?

Comment: well, if your application is really multilanguage - then yes, you have. The second option is to store texto values in converted ways, adding the coumn like texto_simplified where to save strings in "normal" alphabet, but it can be costy in terms of db spase - so it depends on taks really.